# Google oauth - getting the user email

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, flask-dance

I am using Flask dance in order to authenticate users (using Google as auth provider) I try to get the user email and tried few options - non of them returned the email.

Code snippet:(google is flak-dance Google blue print)

```
   if not google.authorized:
            return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
   else:
       resp = google.get(url)
```

I have tried the following urls:

1. https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
3. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
4. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo

I was using the scope: `scope=["profile", "email"]` when the Google blueprint was created. The data structure that I get as result is:

```
{'sub': 'XYZ', 'name': 'XYZ', 'given_name': 'XYZ',
 'family_name': 'XYZ', 'picture': 'XYZ', 'locale': 'XYZ'}
```

On page https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent, Under the 'OAuth consent screen' page, under the section 'Scopes for Google APIs' I have the following entries:

- email
- profile
- openid

My question is:

How do I get the the fields above **and** the user's email?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get the user email: (plus few other fields)

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?fields=id,email,name,picture

Comment: Perfect, actually your *question* solved my problem, thanks mate !